# MATLAB: Plotting lines inside an RGB Cube

Tags: matlab, graph-visualization

I'm a MATLAB newbie and while I've found a few ways to create and show a RGB cube, I haven't figured out how to plot something within it.

Here's some context: I've got a few approaches to [colour cycling](http://www.effectgames.com/effect/article.psp.html/joe/Old_School_Color_Cycling_with_HTML5) implemented in javascript/html5.  Concretely, my first attempt naively interpolates between provided "endpoints" in the RGB-colour space, another approach performs a similar translation in HSV-colour space.

What I'd like to do is gain some geometric intuition as to what my different models of colour cycling actually look like if I were to plot out the transitions in an RGB-cube.  So to that end, I need to do the following:

**1. Create a RGB Cube** (I can already do this by cutting/pasting a solution that uses patch() that was found [here](https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ifcb-web/repository/revisions/2/entry/trunk/dipum_toolbox_registered/dipum_1.1.3/rgbcube.m)

**2. Plot my colour cycling models inside a semi-translucent RGB Cube from 1**

Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: So, what is it *exactly* that you want to do in Matlab? Color cycling inside an RGB cube seems quite a fuss!

Comment: what would you expect to see, the notion of a semi-transparent RGB-cube is a bit problematic, there are 2 options: (1) you can have a "shell" of a cube i.e. a hollow cube where only the colors on the surface matter (problem is that the surface is not representative of the interior) (2) have a full cube, here thers a problem with the projection i.e. every pixel on screen will be a weighted sum of a ray though the cube, again not very representative of anything, my suggestion would be to draw just the path and make the data points the correct color based on location...

Comment: to make it clear, think of having a point at the center of the cube, an imagine looking at it from different directions. in both the options i presented the same point will seem to be positioned on different colors. if you have a different idea of what a 2d projection of a semi-translucent RGB cube is please provide it.

Comment: @pseudoDust I think you're bang on with your suggestion about drawing just the path and setting the individual points to the correct color. 

I think that works just as well (if not better) than my original plan.  Is there an easy way to change the colour of each individual data point?

Comment: sure, use `scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)` so if you have a n by 3 matrix of colors say `RGB = rand(10,3)` you can use `scatter3(RGB(:,1),RGB(:,2),RGB(:,3),100,RGB,'.')` then you can use `hold on` and `plot3(RGB(:,1),RGB(:,2),RGB(:,3))` to add the path. it might also look better if you interpolate the data with a spline instead of plot3, but that's a bit more advanced, let me know if you need help with that...